# Two character last names using apacite and bibtex

Tags: bibtex, apacite

I'm using apacite and bibtex, and something strange happens with a couple of my authors who have two character last names.

For example, I have the following author entry in the bibtex file:

```
author={Ng, Janet W. and Nielsen, Charlene and St. Clair, Colleen Cassady}
```

But for some reason, rather than showing up as (Ng, Nielsen, and St. Clair, YEAR) in in-text citations like I want it to, it shows up as (J. W. Ng, Nielsen, and St. Clair, YEAR). This only happens to authors with two character last names.

Why is this happening and how can I stop it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a full bib entry, not just an author field. Please also tell us which options (if any) you pass to the `apacite` package and which citation command you use. FWIW, I am unable to reproduce the issue you've described if I load the `apacite` package with the option `natbibapa` and use a `\citep` instruction to generate a citation call-out.

Comment: Full bib entry:

    `@article{Ng08,
    author={Ng, Janet W. and Nielsen, Charlene and St. Clair, Colleen Cassady},
    title={Landscape and traffic factors influencing deer-vehicle collisions in an urban environment},
    year=2008,
    journal={Human-Wildlife Conflicts},
    volume={2},
    number={1},
    pages={34-47},
    }`

All I have at the bottom of the document is 

    `\bibliographystyle{apacite}
    \bibliography{bridges}`

And I call the citation using 

    `\cite{Ng08}`

Hopefully that provides more info

Comment: Please state if you're using the `apacite` package.

Comment: Yes. I believe the only packages I'm using that should affect the bibliography are `apacite` and `url`.